# How to find the SID of an Oracle Database using SQL Query

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am developing an app and have a working connection to a Oracle Database using a Connection String like this:

```
"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcpcomm)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mydatabasehost.myserver.com)(PORT=1529))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=code123.myserver.com))); User Id=user;Password=123456;";
```

I checked and I can also connect to this database using Oracle SQL Developer on my laptop.

Now I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database using Azure Logic Apps Oracle Connector.
[image: Azure Logic Apps Connector]
But it requires:

```
serverhost:port/sid
```

I tried only serverhost:port but it also does not connect, gives this an error like this:

> Test connection failed. Details: Oracle: ORA-12154: TNS:could not
> resolve the connect identifier specified inner exception: Oracle:
> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
> clientRequestId:

I tried these 3 queries:

```
select distinct sid from v$mystat;
select * from global_name;
select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';
```

But none of the returned values worked locally when I select SID.
[image: Oracle SQL Developer] 
I get

> Invalid Username/password; logon denied

On Logic Apps this error appear:
Failed to create connection for connection id

> '/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_oracle/connections/shared-oracle-....'.
> Encountered internal server error from Data Transfer Service. The
> tracking Id is '...'.

Locally, if I use the SERVICE_NAME then it works. But in order to use the Logic Apps connector I need the SID.

I checked the **On-premises data gateway** Network ports test and it says:
[image: On-premisses data gateway]

How can I find out the SID by typing a SQL Query into my existing Oracle Connection on Oracle SQL Developer? Or how can I connect from Azure Logic Apps using the SERVICE_NAME?

Is it possible that the server is not accepting connections using the SID, and only accepts connections using the Service Name?

Comment: `serverhost:port/sid` is technically 'wrong'.  This 'easy connect' syntax is `serverhost:port/service_name`.  It doesn't work with (now obsolete) SIDs, so avoid being distracted by answers about SIDs!

Comment: WHen I try `serverhost:port/service_name` then the error is `Failed to create connection for connection id '/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_oracle/connections/shared-oracle-...'. Encountered internal server error from Data Transfer Service. The tracking Id is ...`

Comment: Is the target database a _pluggable_ database (PDB)?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the SID by querying the v$thread view in the existing Oracle SQL Developer connection:

If ORACLE_SID = DB_SID

```
SQL> select instance from v$thread;
INSTANCE
----------------
DB_SID
```

More info on DB_NAME and ORACLE_SID [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:318216852435)

Comment: When I run this query, it returns `ORA-00942: a tabela ou view não existe 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"`

Comment: select instance_name from v$instance; would give you the sid.

Comment: I ran that and when I use that instance name on the Oracle SQL Developer SID field with the login and password (that works with Service Name) it gives `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

Comment: If you are getting ORA-01017 it means you are connecting to some database but the user and password you tried to login with do not work.

Answer (score 2):

My first answer was lame. You are getting this error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
```

So, it is trying to look up your server in a tnsnames.ora file rather than use host, port, sid or service name. It could be that there is another option that lets you type all that in. Or you may need to install an oracle client and setup a tnsnames.ora entry for your target server.

tnsnames.ora entry would look something like this:

```
MYSERVER=
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcpcomm)(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
(HOST=mydatabasehost.myserver.com)(PORT=1529))(CONNECT_DATA= 
(SERVICE_NAME=code123.myserver.com)))
```

Bobby

Comment: Is it possible that the server is configured to not accepting connections using the SID, and only accepts connections using the Service Name?

Comment: It is unlikely. There are some funky ways things can be setup but most likely the issue is that Azure Logic Apps Oracle Connector expects you to have an Oracle client installed and the host, port, sid/service_name in the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-oracledatabase - the docs say to enter a server port and sid so I don't know. It also says to install a client. ORA-12154 usually means it cannot find a service name in a tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: Hey, I did not pay attention to that information: Install the Oracle Client on the machine where you installed the on-premises data gateway. Be sure to install the 64-bit Oracle Data Provider for .NET from Oracle:

64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64

Comment: I created the `tnsnames.ora` file on C:\oracle and put the connection string, but still getting `TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified` and also not being to connect using the SID on Oracle SQL Developer. Perhaps that server is not accepting connections using SID?

Comment: The tnsnames.ora file goes in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin usually.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the Oracle SID with the query

```
SELECT sys_context('userenv','db_name') FROM DUAL;
```

It is accessible by every user, you don't need special privileges to use it.

Comment: I tried this, then used the value on the SID field, tried to connect and got this:
`Listener refused the connection with the following error:ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`